# ID column in Sharepoint How it Cols in Internal name, and in Display Name

Tags: development

How calls a ID Sharepoint Column. Internal name.

In ItemAdding I have got that code at Event Receiver:

`item["ID z Czas Pracy Wpisy"] = properties.AfterProperties["Identyfikator"];`

Comment: It show me null.

Comment: The same `item["ID z Czas Pracy Wpisy"] = properties.AfterProperties["Identyfikator"];`